# Insert procedure syntax

Tags: sql

need help with **SQL SERVER** cause i dont know what's the correct syntax, couldt find a useful answer on google.

Only want to insert a varchar text into the table

```
    create table nombre_usuario(nombre varchar(25))

    create procedure insertar_datos (@insertar varchar(25)) as 
    insert into insertar_datos(nombre)
    values (@insertar)

    exec insertar_datos('pepe');

///error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
///Incorrect syntax near 'pepe'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your procedure call, do not use parenthesis, but do name your parameters. This is not necessary, but is the best practice to avoid problems.

```
exec insertar_datos @insertar = 'pepe';
```

Comment: i created again the procedure without parenthesis and works, thnks.

but how is the correct statement to execute the procedure for the way i did?. please

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using a "procedure"? I do *strongly* recommend using stored procedures for interfacing with SQL from a client program. But if you are just doing a simple insert using a tool like SSMS, then you just need:

`INSERT INTO insertar_datos(nombre) VALUES ('pepe')`

Also, since I assume that, based on the table and column names, this database will be used with language(s) other than English, I highly recommend you use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. That will allow extended characters that are not available in the ASCII set.